# css dropdown not working

Tags: html, css

Practicing on anchor tags and drop down menu. In the following code, the dropdown is not working. Don't know why. The div containing text "This is dropdown menu" should appear exactly below the div containing text "This is text. Its in center" whenever the later is hovered upon. Both the divs are of same width.

```css
html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 /* [disabled]width: 100%; */
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.wrapper {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 height: 100%;
 max-width: 960px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}

.link1 {
 height: auto;
 width: 50%;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
}

.link1 a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}

.link1 a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1); 
}

.link1 a:hover .dropdown {
 display: block;
}


.dropdown

{
 height: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="link1">
<a href="http://www.hotmail.com">This is text. Its in center</a>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">This is dropdown menu</div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's because your .dropdown element is not a sibling of the link.

Comment: could you please give with code example so that i can better understand?

Answer (score 1):

Your css selector `.link1 a:hover .dropdown` selects the element with the class `dropdown` which has to be inside of an a element in a hover state (`a:hover`), which is inside an element with a class of `link1`.

This doesn't match your html markup.

To get it work, you can change your html to this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="link1">
          <a href="http://www.hotmail.com">
              This is text. Its in center
              <div class="dropdown">This is dropdown menu</div>
          </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: but in that case, the dropdown div takes the background color of the `.link1 a:hover` and also its width does not matches as the above div

Answer (score 1):

Lexith is partly right, you need to add the dropdown within the container div, you can then select the sibling of the hovered a link.

Like so;

CSS -

```
.link1 a:hover + .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML -

```
<div class="link1">
  <a href="http://www.hotmail.com">This is text. Its in center</a>
  <div class="dropdown">This is dropdown menu</div>
</div>
```

CSS update -
This allows the dropdown to stay open when hovering on it

```
.dropdown:hover,
.link1 a:hover + .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

This means it doesnt have any of the a tag styling. [View my code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXMxRB)

Comment: Better than my answer. I keep forgetting the possibility to select siblings with `+`.

Comment: What's easily done? Remembering the `+` operator or providing better answers than me? :D

Comment: Thanks for the laugh in the morning :D